# Как передать экземпяр в качестве агрумента метода?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть метод (fragmentUsing), в него нужно передать один с экземпляров класса типа (fragment1 or fragment2 or fragment3 or fragment4):

```
Fragment1 fragment1=NewFragment1();
Fragment2 fragment2=NewFragment2();
Fragment3 fragment3=NewFragment3();
Fragment4 fragment4=NewFragment4();

public void fragmentUsing (** ***){
    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainLayout,***,TAG_1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Как это сделать ?

Comment: Экземпляр класса - это объект. Объявите его тип и имя в описании метода (получится *параметр*). Например `public void fragmentUsing (int i)`. вызывайте так: `fragmentUsing(4)`. 4 тут будет экземпляром класса `int`

Comment: @metalurgus вот только тип динамическим.

Comment: типы динамическими не бывают

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип параметра укажите тот, от которого наследуются все эти `NewFragment`. Если они наследуются от `Fragment`, то укажите его.

```
public void fragmentUsing (Fragment fragment){
    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainLayout, fragment,TAG_1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ток с android.support.v4.app.Fragment ошибку дает

Comment: @user208111, это потому, что у вас `android.app.FragmentTransaction` и `getFragmentManager();`, а надо `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` и `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: спасибо за объяснение, вот только у меня `getSupportFragmentManager()` не находит если `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`

Comment: @user208111, значит Activity у вас наследуется не от той, которая нужна.